# Is frequent sleep-wakeup harmful to the electronics?

Tags: microcontroller, power

I'm programming a large network of [tiny microcontrollers](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/mmc/FM141/SC1244/SS1010/LN2/PF251792) (say around 500 of them, but easily more) that communicate with SPI with a hierarchy of masters (say each master controls 32 of them).

Given these numbers, the power consumption of this network can easily get high and I'm trying to keep that under control. It would be ok if there are very short peaks in current consumption, but it shouldn't last long of course.

I have been thinking of frequently switching to a low power mode any chance I get:

1. Between SPI transactions: this can be powering down, even to halt mode (which turns off all peripherals) and back up as frequent as a couple of times every 40 *ms*.
2. During the SPI transactions: this means powering down slightly (only turn off the CPU) and back up with every byte transfer, e.g. every 2 *us* during the transaction.

Now I'm a software guy, so my knowledge of electronics when it comes to their electrical characteristics is limited.

My question, can this damage the hardware? Is turning the CPU off and on every 2us unhealthy? What about turning everything off a few times every 40ms?

Answer (score 3):

The hardware itself won't care, but if you're using an external crystal then it will take some time before the clock stabilizes, on the order of tens of milliseconds. If you want quick wakeup then you should switch to using an external oscillator (and possibly clock distribution ICs, if you want to share an oscillator between several to several dozen MCUs) and then configure the MCU to skip as much of the clock stabilization delay as possible.

Comment: You are correct about crystals in that they take many cycles to get going and stabalize.  However, internal R-C oscillators are capable of starting up very quickly.  They are a *good* choice when low latency is required getting out of sleep.

Comment: It's good that the hardware doesn't care. Can you back the fact up, please, to be precise?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I was thinking the same. Thanks for the answer, the part about the clock was also informative.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Read the datasheet. Look for "fully static operation".

Comment: @Ignacio: static operation (no clock) is not the same as powered off!

Comment: @radagast: The question says "switching to a low power mode", so I don't think the asker intends to cut off the supply to the chip completely.

Answer (score 1):

It would certainly be possible to construct hardware which would be damaged by frequent cycling, but with the kinds of power levels used by most microcontrollers there would be really little purpose to doing so.  The situations in which power-cycling tends to be damaging are most often those in which startup power requirements are so much higher than running power that heat-dissipation ability sufficient to handle the higher requirements continuously would be more expensive than ability sufficient to handle them intermittently.  At the power levels associated with microcontrollers, there's seldom any difficulty ensuring that heat dissipation will be sufficient for continuous worst-case operation.

Note that if instead of microcontrollers, one were talking about processors that are so powerful as to require fans and heat sinks, then frequent sleep/wake-up cycles might start to become a problem, especially if processors needed to be able to wake-up and start working without waiting for the fans to get up to speed.  For microcontrollers that consume milliwatts instead of tens or hundreds of watts, however, that's really not an issue.